# java regex for 38k to 38000

Tags: java, regex

How do I change 38k  to 38000? or 43k to 48000 etc

I tried this

```
String s0=toClean.replaceAll("[0-9]k", "[0-9]000");
```

But its wrong. It changes 38k to 309000

Comment: `toClean.replace("k","000")` ?

Comment: @khe OP didn't say there's nothing else in the string.

Comment: The OP didn't say there _is_ anything else in the string. If there is more in the string, they should really give example input/output.

Comment: 1+ for at least trying and not looking for a handout :)

Comment: Yi000es, I didn't thin000 that my question could be interpreted li000e that. But here's $1000 for pointing it out. Than000s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only one digit, but multiple (so add `+`). Also, you should capture that number and return it with the capture group 1 (`$1`) and check if there's nothing else after `k` (e.g. so as `38kabc` wouldn't be valid)

```
String s0=toClean.replaceAll("([0-9]+)k\\b", "$1000");
```

Comment: To be more strict, maybe add `\b` after `k`?

Comment: @Andreas Hm, makes sense. Edited.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, forgot that needs escaping - sorry.